# Recursively drawing tree using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am trying to recursively draw a tree based on a dataset. Each level 0 item is added a class `category` (which has bold text styling) , each level 1 is added `group` and level 2 is added `leaf`. This tree can be drawn up to two levels. But when I am recursively drawing the tree, all the levels get bold styling and mouse hover as well is applying to whole instead of each level.

Here is the sandbox that shows both the trees , one drawn using recursion other one is hardcoded using css: https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-compared-9s828h

Can someone tell me what is wrong in the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't render the children inside the parent. Render them as a new row by wrapping both with a [Fragment (`<>...</>`)](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment). The fragment doesn't create a new DOM element, and allows you to recursively render a flat list, like your static tree.

Code ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-tree-forked-pmr94k?file=/src/DrawnTree.jsx)):

```
return (
  <>
    <div
      className={`list-row level-${level} ${categoryType}`}
      onClick={onClickNode}
      key={`${node.key}`}
    >
      <div className="list-item-holder">
        {hasChildren && (
          <div className="list-item-expander-holder">
            <span
              className={`expand-collapse-icon ${isLeaf ? '' : 'expand'}`}
            >
              <span className="collapse-icon">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />
              </span>
              <span className="expand-icon">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-right" />
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="list-item-details-holder">{node.name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {hasChildren && (
      <div className="list-row-children">
        {node.categories.map((category) => renderNode(category, level + 1))}
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Ori Dori, thanks for the answer, some how `level-1` items are coming towards the sidemost left when compared to hardcoded tree. Consider, `Windows` and `VS Code`. Also what how can I dynamically expand and collapse each items?  . https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-compared-forked-bqgjq2?file=/src/data.js

Comment: You need to add the correct CSS rules for each level. Note that now you also have level-3.
To dynamically expend and collapse, you'll need to create a component with state for a level.

Comment: Create a **component** for levels. The component should hold the JSX of the current item and the children. Each component should have an open state (`useState()`), and you can toggle the state by clicking the level.

Comment: See updated sandbox. Note how I converted the function to a component with state.